# Short story about robots on a farm after losing communications, go out to rule the world

Tags: story-identification

Several types of robot work on an automated farm. One by one they realize there have been no communications from the City for some time, and the humans may be gone. They stop working, decide after a quite comical conversation that they will rule the world together (or similar), and head off down the road toward the City full of plans. One small robot falls off a big one and is left to die. At a river they meet a dirty creature drinking the water and they all bow down and cry “Master!”

Comment: You also asked [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34378/id-of-golden-age-sf-story-about-a-colonized-planet-of-telepathic-plant-life) - all good - but any chance it's from the same anthology/year?  Keep in mind that ['Golden Age'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Science_Fiction) in terms of sci-fi were the 'distraction-attractive years' between 1938 and 1946.

Comment: No, I definitely encountered the other one separately. I accept Silverberg's inclusion of the 1950s in the Golden Age, so I estimate that both were likely published no later than 1960.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short story pre 1990 involving different classes of machines confused without man. Man arrives at end](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/short-story-pre-1990-involving-different-classes-of-machines-confused-without-ma)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the short story "But who can replace a Man?" by Brian Aldiss.

[Wiki Aldiss Site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Aldiss)

Comment: Yep---thanks! Well done.