# Story about a colonized planet of butterflies that are telepathic plant life

Tags: story-identification, novel

All I remember about this story (possibly a novel or novella, possibly by Poul Anderson) is that the butterflies on this planet are plants. The author uses a clever latinate word based on “phyto” to name these forms. Also, no one realizes the plants are telepathic.

Contact with the plants may be forbidden or deadly; may have been the first of two stories set on the planet. Sorry the details are so vague—I am sure I read it only once.

Comment: [Poul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Anderson) is very post-[Golden Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Science_Fiction)  Can you actually date the story?

Comment: Nope. I only mention P.A. because I remember making a mental note to that effect---but it was about 40 years ago. Could have been from as late as the 1960s.

Comment: Okay, understandable that it was a bit ago- how did it feel in your hands?  It's going to be a harder one, so- where were you while you read it?

Comment: That memory is lost, unfortunately. I'm sure it was a hardback library book. I seem to recall that something about the plants was forbidden on pain of death . . . and that there was a continuation or part 2. I'll change the tag to "novel."

Comment: Thanks David. That must be it---even though the phytozoons are apparently the only thing I remembered correctly!

Comment: Incidentally, here's the cover to that issue of F&SF: http://www.flickr.com/photos/23023719@N04/2442689964/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like the novelette ["Hunter, Come Home"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58489) (1963), by Richard McKenna.  In this story, which deals with an attempt to terraform the planet by releasing the killer plant *Thanasis* to destroy the native ecosystem, the butterflies are called "phytozoons", or "phytos" for short, and are "mixed plant and animal".  According to the bibliographical information in front of me, this story is a revised version of ["The Night of Hoggy Darn"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58473) (1958), which I have not read.  This might account for your remembering it as two stories.