# Identify Story: 60's or 70's novella about last man alive taken care of by robots

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone remember the name of a story (I think it was a novella from the 1960's or 70's) about the last man left alive on earth after a nuclear war, who is taken care of by a group of robots who gradually evolve into a sentient species?

Comment: Not much to go on there. Please try to recall more details; anything, no matter how unimportant it may seem. I'm afraid there are a **bunch** of last-man-with-robots stories. Nuclear war helps narrow it down a little. Robots becoming sentient doesn't help so much; sci-fi robots are sentient more often than not.

Comment: What role does the man play in the story? Do the robots "evolve sentience" while the man is around to interact with them, or does that happen after the man is dead and gone?

Comment: This question is similar, and you might be thinking of one of the stories suggested in the answers there: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/short-story-pre-1990-involving-different-classes-of-machines-confused-without-ma/24063#24063

Comment: My bet is "Who Can Replace a Man?" - the description here may jog the OP's memory: http://www.antiessays.com/free-essays/333101.html

Answer (score 9):

I found this http://techland.time.com/2010/05/04/the-last-man-in-a-universe-of-robots/
The Story is :
Second Ending goes like this: guy wakes up from long hypersleep to discover that the rest of humanity has died out around him. All that’s left are a bunch of service robots, one of whom woke him up. Our hero, Ross, is pretty bummed that he’s the last human being alive. He misses his wife/girlfriend (I forget which) Alice.

Slowly he starts exploring the ruined Earth he’s inherited. The dead sea, the irradiated earth, etc. He deploys platoons of robots to search for other people, or any life at all, and eventually just for food. At the same time the robots start evolving from clunky automata to sophisticated devices. The process accelerates as Ross starts going in and out of hypersleep — he’ll have himself put down for a couple of centuries while the robots work on a project, then when he wakes up the Earth will have degenerated further, and the robots will have gone through a couple of hundred iterations. Eventually we get into a strange deep future, with energy beings and a dying sun …

Comment: I think you're right-it's Second Ending by James White.
The robots manage to revitalise Earth using grass seeds they find in the man's trouser cuffs.
At the end they send him to another planet, which has green-skinned humanoids.

Comment: Right on!  Thanks you guys rock! That is the story I've been looking for.  My mom tossed out my entire stack of pulps, fictions and comics after I moved out - 20 years ago - and that was one of those stories that I really missed reading again.